# How to send multipart/form data with array from Java?

Tags: java, http, http-post

When I use Postman, I send a request like "form-data", and it works.

I know how to make a request, but I do not know how to assemble the body of such a request.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI9dd.jpg)

The resource to which I should send the post request expects this format:

```
array 
(
   "data" =>  array
        (
            0 =>  array 
            (
                "external_id" => 123, 
                "count"       => 1,
                "price"       => 1000,
            ),
        1 =>  array 
            (
                "external_id" => 345,
                "count"       => 2,
                "price"       => 2000,
            ),
        2 =>  array 
            (
                "external_id" => 456,
                "count"       => 3,
                "price"       => 3000,
            ),
    ),
```

)

**Thanks for any help.**

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with this in raw format?

I think when it comes to JSON structures a PHP array is taken like a JSON object. So what you would need to do here is to put all your JSON inside a data field of content-type application/json as shown in this screenshot and it should work. Let me know how it goes. [image: postman screenshot]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint that this is PHP, after that I was able to figure out what they want from me. I built the request body in this form:

String query = data[0][price]=1000&data[0][count]=1&data[0][external_id]=123

next I passed it to my call Api Method with properties: 

connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

After that, it worked for me.